# Linear Layout resize inside ScrollView when keypad input appears

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with my layout.

I have a scroll view inside which has a linear layout and inside the linear layout has some TextInputLayout.

And if a user is focused on a text input and the user pressed the Linear Layout (without any text input), the text input will be unfocused. I have set the input's parent, Linear Layout, to be focusable.
I want the user to press on any area that is not a text input and the focused input will be unfocused.

That's why my scroll view width and height are matched parent and the linear layout inside it is match parent for its width to make it cover the whole screen. But not the height for Linear Layout, as the height should be wrap content

When the text input is focused and the keyboard input shows up, everything will be pushed up a little bit and I can scroll them vertically.

But, when I scroll below beyond the keyboard, the linear layout seems to not be there anymore as it seems to cropped out left only the scroll view which means if user press on there then they will not be unfocused.

I have tried various methods like adjustPan, adjustResize, fillViewPort Weight but none of them work. Please help. I attached two screenshots below.

Note:
*I have set Scroll View background to purple and Linear Layout to blue for ease of visualizing.*

This screenshot is when the app starts, no keyboard input, everything is fine.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MqIL.png

This is where the keyboard input shows up, and if I try to clear focus by pressing on the purple area, it won't work. I want the blue or Linear Layout to cover all the Scroll View.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6jCn.png

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Share your files with question ..

Comment: wow off-topic! Incredible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all paddings from linear layout and give it in TextInputLayout and take a height of linear layout is match parent like

android:layout_height="match_content"